# Data Base design turnkey records

Tags: sql, database

I have some questions regarding data base design for simple CMS.

Every Page in Table "PAGES" could be "AssignedTo" and "LockedBy" by a specific User.
To manage Users I am using SQL specific table "aspnet_Users", every User is identified using a GUI uniqueIdentifier column.

If a page is "Unlock" and can be edited by Users, its value in Table "Pages" would be NULL, same mechanism for "AssignedTo".

Here my script when I create Table "PAGES":

```
LockedBy uniqueidentifier NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES aspnet_users(UserId),
AssignedTo uniqueidentifier NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES aspnet_users(UserId)
```

My question:
This design will generate many NULL values in "LockedBy" since Pages will be locked only in the moment of editing, because I heard have many NULL values is not a good thing in Data Base design,, I would like to know if my design is in good practice, or if you could suggest a better way.
Thanks guys

Comment: I read that as "turkey records"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I think it's a good idea to have this in one table, ignoring the fact that there's many NULL values, but here's another solution:

You could split this into two other tables:
PageLocks and PageAssignedTo

PageLocks:
PageID, UserID <- unique key

PageAssignedTo:
PageID, UserID <- unique key

Comment: thanks for your message, do you think your solution with Two Table could be resulting better in performace? thanks

Comment: It depends. In SQL Server 2008 you've got filtered indexes, so adding one index (on each field) in your Pages-table would be the same as splitting it out in another table